# How to persist array data inside UDT objects between bars?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am developing an indicator that has several UDTs. Some of these UDTs have array of other UDTs that are added/removed dynamically on every tick.

This is the pattern I am following to organize my code:

```
type TDetail
    int oneThing
    int anotherThing
//
// This has a collection of TDetail objects.
type TMaster
    array<TDetail> details = na
//
// Some sort of factory function.
createMaster() =>
    array<TDetail> details = array.new<TDetail>()
    TMaster result = TMaster.new(details=details)
    (result)
//
// Initialize the master object only once.
var TMaster master = createMaster()
//
// Some logic on every tick...
if (someConditionIsTrue)
    TDetail detail = TDetail.new(...properties values go here...)
    master.details.push(detail)
```

I noticed, however, that the items are not persisted between the ticks. What am I missing?

I also tried "debugging" with a logging-type library, which I noticed that the arrays were always empty, instead of saving the previous TDetail objects.

Comment: I am aware that we can now use 'varip' keyword in UDT, but unfortunatelly the compiler does not allow in array fields.